# How a time gap between two dates should be phrased?

Tags: phrase-request

I recently wrote this in a document as a summary of a task:

> This process verifies the structure and makes sure "date2" is equal to supplied "date1" minus 1 month.

The phrase

> is equal to "date1" minus 1 month

sounds clumsy to me.  Is it okay or are there better turns of phrase?

Thank you.

Comment: You one typo and "equal to supplied month" is meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you've written it would be easily understood by a software developer or engineer, but I think you're right that it's awkward in other settings. Any of the following would be acceptable to a layperson. The terms 'prior to', 'before', 'earlier than' are interchangeable.

> Date2 is equal to a month prior to the supplied date, Date1
> Date2 is equal to a month before Date1, which is supplied
> Date2 is a month earlier than the supplied Date1

Comment: I didn't expect someone to answer my question now it has been down-voted. Thank you for the time!

Comment: You're welcome. I think it's a good question